# RecyclerView wont set adapter after implementing onClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing `onclicklistener` and `onlongclicklistener` in my adapter for my recycler view and 
my `recyclerview` wont display after inserting Context in the constructor of my adapter class. Below shows my adapter class and activity `onCreate`

**ListingNearbyAdapter.Class**

```
public class ListingNearbyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListingNearbyAdapter.ListingNearbyViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<ListingNearby> listings = new ArrayList<ListingNearby>();
    Context context;

    public ListingNearbyAdapter(ArrayList<ListingNearby> listings, Context context){
        this.listings = listings;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ListingNearbyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listing_nearby_row_layout,parent,false);
        ListingNearbyViewHolder listingNearbyViewHolder = new ListingNearbyViewHolder(view, context, listings);

        return listingNearbyViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListingNearbyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListingNearby list = listings.get(position);
        holder.property_name.setText("Property Name:  " + list.getProperty_name());
        holder.type.setText("Property Type:  " + list.getType());
        holder.price.setText("Price:  PHP " + list.getPrice());
        holder.distance.setText("Distance:  " + String.valueOf(list.getDistance()) + " km");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listings.size();
    }

    public static class ListingNearbyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{
        TextView property_name, type, price, distance;
        ArrayList<ListingNearby> listings = new ArrayList<ListingNearby>();
        Context context;

        public ListingNearbyViewHolder(View view, Context context, ArrayList<ListingNearby> listings){
            super(view);
            this.listings = listings;
            this.context = context;
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);

            property_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ln_property_name);
            type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ln_type);
            price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ln_price);
            distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ln_distance);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            ListingNearby listingNearby = this.listings.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, PropertyDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("property_id", listingNearby.getProperty_id());
            this.context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> OnCreate:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ln_recycler_view);
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    adapter = new ListingNearbyAdapter(list, this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i dont know where is the error, thanks in advance.

Comment: where do i get the context required for the adapter?

Comment: @Zeeshan why not passing context? Can´t see anywhere a hint in the API that this is not recommended....am I blind?

Comment: Don't make your class implement `OnClickListener`, instead, create a new listener for each item inside `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: sorry, this is a duplicate. Search further, I will have to flag as dup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs why pass context from activity to adapter when context is already there? Doesn't make sense. Its not base adapter or array adapter.

Comment: @Chisko `"instead, create a new listener for each item inside onBindViewHolder()"` so if you have 1000 items in your `RecyclerView` and you browse them all you will end in 1000 instances of the listener, if you implement `OnClickListener` inside `ViewHolder` you have 10-15 listeners max

Comment: @pskink RecyclerView is already optimized so you don't have to deal with non-critical issues like this

Comment: @Chisko sorry, it is optimized for over allocation of the listeners? do you know when `onBindViewHolder` is called? and do you know how often you will create your listeners?

Comment: Yes. A list with a 1000 items is very useful to an end user...

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir you mean getting the context out of the `View` ? But what if the context is needed for other work not related to the `View`?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs what other work? can you mention please

Comment: for example, calling another method from another class that needs context. just a simple scenario, no special one. If you want to do some stuff that is not related to the view directly, you also need a context. In some circumstances, it´s needed, than I guess using parameters is useful.

Comment: @Chisko it does not matter if it has 1000 items or 100 items but browsed 5 times top and bottom

Comment: Feel free to give a good answer with the amount of info and context the OP gave and I'll gladly upvote you or whatever you want

Comment: I agree with pskink, that´s a good point, that I also not thought about. For example a chat app, you will have so much views after a while, than I think it´s not a resource saving way.

Comment: danke @Opiatefuchs, thats why `ViewHolder` has `get*Position()` methods

Comment: Yes it is a valid view. But we went really off the question.

Comment: yeah, back to the question: Does the app crash or just nothing happens?